# How do I disable a Wijmo Menu item?

Tags: jquery, menu, wijmo

Is it possible to disable a Wijmo menu item?

I have the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/3CQGC/), and I'd like to disable a menu option (either a branch or a leaf) if the user doesn't have a certain permission.  I've tried setting the `<li>` and the `<a>` tags of the node to have the `disabled` attribute.  I've tried setting `disabled='disabled'` and `disabled='true'` and `disabled=true`, but can't get the menu item to disable.

The API for the menu component doesn't seem to have a method to disable an item, so I'm assuming I would just disable the element in the DOM.

In my fiddle, there is a leaf (Politics -- the second node under the first parent Breaking News) that has a URL associated to it.  I'd like to be able to disable this item.

Is it possible to disable a Wijmo menu item?  If so, how?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Going to look into exposing the disabled option on items too. Currently we only surface it on root widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a disable option added to the root menu. I don't think that is what you want though. I would just do soemthing similar to Kevin's recommendation, but still use the disabled attr. Like so:

```
$("#flyoutmenu").wijmenu();
$("#flyoutmenu a[disabled]").parent().addClass("ui-state-disabled").end().click(function () {
   return false;
});
```

You can also add a little CSS to make it look disabled. Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3CQGC/3/

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just not display the branch or leaf you'd like to disable?

All the items on the menu are hyperlinks, so you can't disable them.

OR there is the trick of:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false" />
```

to make sure the link does nothing when you click on it.

Comment: +1 - Thanks Kevin for the answer.  I may not have the ability (per specs) to remove the branch or leaf I want to disable.  I wanted to see if there was a way to do this with Wijmo menu before attempting to get the specs changed.  Thanks for your input!